# PHP simple nested While loop not looping

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

So this is extremely basic simple stuff. I'm having a little bit of an issue with it here. I don't know if I'm overlooking something here.

```
<?php
while ($supps = tep_db_fetch_array($suppliers_select))
{
    echo"
        <tr class='dataTableHeadingRow'>
            <td class='dataTableHeadingContent'>$supps[entry_company]</td>
        </tr>
    ";

    echo"
        <tr class='dataTableHeadingRow'>
            <td class='dataTableHeadingContent'>Status</td>
            <td class='dataTableHeadingContent'>Current Timestamp</td>
            <td class='dataTableHeadingContent'>Change Timestamp</td>
        </tr>";

    while ($grab_teh_statuses = tep_db_fetch_array($grab_statuses))
    {
        echo"
            <tr class='dataTableRow'>
                <td class='dataTableContent'>
                    $grab_teh_statuses[orders_status_name]
                </td>
                <td class='dataTableContent'>
                    $grab_teh_statuses[time_stamp]
                </td>
                <td class='dataTeableContent'>

                </td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}
?>
```

As you can see, there is a parent While loop and nested inside that While loop there is another While loop. Everything is getting pulled from the database correctly and being populated. The problem I'm running into is the nested While loop only loops once. Wouldn't it loop over and over as many times as the parent While loop goes around?

Comment: No, it would loop enough times to fulfil all the values of `$grab_statuses`, for each iteration of the parent loop.

Comment: it'll be EXECUTED as many times as the parent loop does, but it'll only iterate however many items are returned by the teb_db_fetch_array() call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wouldn't it loop over and over as many times as the parent While loop goes around?

There's nothing to reset the `$grab_statuses` cursor, so in the second and subsequent iterations of the outer loop, the inner loop finishes immediately because there are no more records to fetch.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I sorted it out.